# Real file system accessed when running lxml with pyfakefs

Tags: python, mocking, lxml, pyfakefs

How can I run [lxml](http://lxml.de/) with [pyfakefs](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs)?

```
import os
import unittest
from lxml import etree
from pyfakefs import fake_filesystem_unittest

class TestExample(fake_filesystem_unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.setUpPyfakefs()

    def test_lxml(self):
        os.mkdir('/test')

        root = etree.Element("root")
        tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
        tree.write('/test/file.xml')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When running the example above I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_test.py", line 25, in test_lxml
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 2033, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.write (src/lxml/lx
ml.etree.c:63707)
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 512, in lxml.etree._tofilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree
.c:134950)
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 571, in lxml.etree._create_output_buffer (src/lxml/
lxml.etree.c:135614)
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 560, in lxml.etree._create_output_buffer (src/lxml/
lxml.etree.c:135415)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

---

I am using lxml 3.6.4 and pyfakefs 3.1 in Python 2.7.13 on macOS 10.12.4

Comment: I can reproduce the error with the same versions of Python, lxml and pyfakefs on Windows 10. It works if xml.etree.ElementTree is used instead of lxml.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: `lxml` does not work with pyfakefs. From the [documentation](http://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/release/intro.html#limitations):

> pyfakefs will not work with Python libraries (other than os and io) that use C libraries to access the file system, because it cannot patch the underlying C libraries’ file access functions

And from the troubleshooting chapter:

> pyfakefs uses C libraries to access the file system. There is no way no make such a module work with pyfakefs–if you want to use it, you have to patch the whole module. In some cases, a library implemented in Python with a similar interface already exists. An example is lxml, which can be substituted with ElementTree in most cases for testing.

(replacing `lxml` with `xml.etree.ElementTree` as an alternative for testing has also been mentioned in the comments by @mzjn).